# Email to Case using Apex: Right contact not populating in email message

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, email2case

I am using custom email to case Apex class to create case records. After the case is created I am changing the contact name to some other person. When I goto the email composer salesforce is picking the initial contact but not the current contact of the case. I have attached the code which I used to create the case. Can someone guide me on what is wrong with the code or is this is default salesforce behaivour?

Step:1

[image]

Step: 2
[image]

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,   Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){  
        
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        
        String PlainTextBody = '';
        String HtmlTextBody = '';
        String SubjectText = '';
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        
        PlainTextBody = email.plainTextBody;
        HtmlTextBody = email.htmlBody;
        List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
        List<ContentVersion> lstCV = new List<ContentVersion>();
        List<Attachment> lstAttach = new List<Attachment>();
        List<ContentDocumentLink> lstCDL = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        
        Map<String,String> emailSettingMap = new Map<String,String>();
        try {
            List<Contact> vCon = new List<Contact>();
            vCon = [SELECT Id, Name, Email
                    FROM Contact
                    WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress ORDER BY LastModifiedDate
                    LIMIT 1];
            if(vCon == null || vCon.size() == 0)
            {                   
                String numPat = '[^0-9]';
                Account newAcc = new Account(Name = 'Phone' +' '+ email.fromAddress);
                insert newAcc;
                Contact setCon = new Contact(FirstName = 'Phone', Lastname = email.fromAddress, email = email.fromAddress,Phone = email.fromAddress.replaceAll(numPat,'').right(10) , AccountId = newAcc.Id);
                vCon.add(setCon);
                insert vCon;
            }
            
            else
            {
                vCon = [SELECT Id, Name, Email
                        FROM Contact
                        WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress ORDER BY LastModifiedDate
                        LIMIT 1];
                
                if(vCon == null || vCon.size() == 0)
                {
                    String strSenderName = email.fromName;
                    if(strSenderName.contains(','))
                    {
                        LastName = strSenderName.Substring(0,strSenderName.indexOf(','));
                        FirstName = strSenderName.Substring(strSenderName.indexOf(','),strSenderName.length());
                        FirstName = FirstName.replace(',','');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<String> lstContactName1 = (strSenderName.contains(',')?strSenderName.split(','):strSenderName.split(' '));
                        List<String> lstContactName = strSenderName.split(' ');
                        firstName = lstContactName[0];
                        lastName = lstContactName[1];
                    }
                    
                    Account newAcc = new Account(Name = firstName +' '+ lastname);
                    insert newAcc;
                    Contact setCon = new Contact(firstname = firstName,Lastname = lastname, email = email.fromAddress, AccountId = newAcc.Id);
                    vCon.add(setCon);
                    insert vCon;
                }
            }
            
            List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
            for(String s : email.toAddresses)
            {
                toAddress.add(s);
            }
            //Check to which address the email was sent
            String concatSubjStr = emailSettingMap.get(toAddress[0]);
            lstCase.add(new Case(Status = 'Open',
                                 Origin = 'Email',                                               
                                 SuppliedEmail = email.fromAddress,
                                 Subject = concatSubjStr <> null ? concatSubjStr+email.subject : email.subject,
                                 Description = PlainTextBody,                                
                                 ContactId = vCon[0].Id,                                 
                                 Reason = 'Email to Case',                               
                                 OwnerId = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Case queue' AND Type = 'queue' LIMIT 1].Id
                                ));
            
            if(lstCase.size() > 0)
            {
                insert lstCase;
            }            
            
            List<EmailMessage> newEmail = new List<EmailMessage>();
            
            System.debug('***** Email Value ******* '+email);
            List<String> toaddr = email.toAddresses;
            
            newEmail.add(new EmailMessage(FromAddress = email.fromAddress,
                                          FromName = email.fromName,
                                          ToAddress = vCon[0].Id,
                                          BccIds = null,
                                          Subject =  email.subject,
                                          TextBody = email.plainTextBody,
                                          HtmlBody = email.htmlBody,
                                          RelatedToId  = lstCase[0].Id,
                                          ParentId = lstCase[0].Id,
                                          incoming = true
                                         ));   
            if(newEmail.size() >0)
                insert newEmail;   
            
            EmailMessageRelation emr = new EmailMessageRelation();
            emr.emailMessageId = newEmail[0].Id;
            emr.relationId = vCon[0].Id; // user id of the sender
            emr.relationType = 'FromAddress';
            insert emr;
            
            if(email.binaryAttachments <> null)
            {
                for (Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binAttach : email.binaryAttachments) {
                    ContentVersion singleFile = new ContentVersion();
                    singleFile.Title = binAttach.fileName;
                    singleFile.VersionData = binAttach.body;
                    singleFile.PathOnClient = '/' + binAttach.fileName ;
                    lstCV.add(singleFile);   
                    
                    //Attachment
                    Attachment att=new Attachment();
                    att.Body=binAttach.body;
                    att.Name=binAttach.fileName;
                    att.parentId=newEmail[0].Id;
                    lstAttach.add(att);
                }
            }
            if(lstCV.size() >0)
                insert lstCV;
            
            if(lstAttach.size() >0)
                insert lstAttach;
            
            lstCV = [select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion WHERE Id in :lstCV];
            for (ContentVersion cv : lstCV) {
                ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
                cl.LinkedEntityId = lstCase[0].Id;
                cl.ShareType = 'V';
                cl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                lstCDL.add(cl);
            }
            if(lstCDL.size() >0)
                insert lstCDL;            
        }
        catch (QueryException e) {
            System.debug('**** Exception : ' + e);
        }
        
        result.success = true;    
        return result;
    }
```